# Vue3 Monaco Editor - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, monaco-editor

I'm trying to get the [Monaco Editor Vue3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor-vue3) component to work in my vue3 project.

vue.config.js

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
      
    plugins: [
      new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ['typescript']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

and then importing it inside of a .vue file as per the instructions:

```
import MonacoEditor from 'vue-monaco'

export default {
  components: {
    MonacoEditor
  },

// ...
}
```

However, when I try to `npm run serve` my project, I get the following error:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/_.contribution.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     return lazyLanguageLoaders[languageId];
|   }
>   _languageId;
|   _loadingTriggered;
|   _lazyLoadPromise;
```

as well as other similar errors in different spots of the same file, all pertaining to the absence of a proper loader.

Here's my config files:

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
};
```

package.json

```
//...
  "dependencies": [
    "monaco-editor-vue3": "^0.1.5",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.1",
    // unrelated ...
  ],
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
```

It seems as if there could be a mismatch between the version of ECMAScript the Monaco file is written in and whatever target version my project is using. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here: https://juejin.cn/post/6984683777343619102

I solved the problem by changing the version:

monaco-editor-webpack-plugin: 6.0.0
monaco-editor: 0.30.0